# MYSQL export Value and NOT ID

Tags: mysql, excel, export-to-excel

I have a MYSQL database table called 'wp_quotes' with a field that contains a column called 'media' like below.

'wp_quotes' table

'media' - this column shows '1' or '2' (the ID number) depending on what the user has selected on the form.

I have another table called 'wp_quote_forms_fields_values' that assigns this ID a value - either 'CD' or 'DVD'

'wp_quote_forms_fields_values' table

ID 1 has value of 'CD'

ID 2 has value of 'DVD'

When i run a query (to export a file), how can i get the media column to show 'CD' or 'DVD' instead of '1' or '2'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to join to the table that has the descriptions, like so:

```
SELECT a.ID,a.time,a.quote,b.value as MediaDesc,a.quantity,
c.value As PackDesc,a.username,
a.email,a.company,a.contact_number,a.found_us‌​,a.additional_info 
FROM wp_quotes a
INNER JOIN wp_quote_forms_fields_values b ON b.ID = a.media
INNER JOIN wp_quote_forms_fields_values c ON c.ID = a.pack
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! I am confusing myself with my attempt at a simplified example. ha.
My actual query is....

SELECT ID,time,quote,media,quantity,pack,username,email,company,contact_number,found_us,additional_info FROM wp_quotes

and from this I am getting ID's (not values) for the 'media' and 'pack' tables. I need the values for those two fields.

Could you please revise that example based on my actual query? I just don't understand the a./b. thing.

Comment: perhaps instead you can let me know what is actual code and what is specific to my example? is a. and b. made up? or the actual code i use? is description_table made up? or the actual name I use? Been playing with this for 2 hours and returning nothing.

Comment: @lowercase - If you edit your question to include the schema for the tables you are using in the query, I should be able to give you the actual code.

Comment: @lowercase - the `a` and `b` are just table aliases - and yes, description_table is made up.  You would replace that with the table containing the id/value pairs (you didn't specify what the name of that table was)

Comment: Thanks again - I have re-edited the original question in an attempt to explain things better. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I stand corrected. This works great for one field ('pack'). I can get the packaging name instead of it's id using this...

SELECT a.ID, a.time, a.quote, a.quantity, a.media, a.print, a.pack, a.delivery, a.username, a.email, a.company, a.contact_number, a.found_us, a.additional_info, b.value FROM wp_quotes a

INNER JOIN wp_quote_forms_fields_values b ON b.ID = a.pack

How now can I adapt this to do the same for 3 other values ('media', 'delivery' and 'print')? Is that possible using 'value' or do I need 3 separate identifiers? maybe different letters for each new one instead of a/b?

Comment: @lowercase - yes, you can just join to the wp_quote_forms_fields_values multiple times for each ID field you need.  I updated my example to do it twice (for media and pack).  Not sure what the third one was, but you would just add another join (call it `d` or something) using the 3rd field.

Comment: when i export though - i can't use the 'value' field name twice it seems, so it won't work for the other items. if i try to use b.value, it fails again. how do you do this across multiple tables when the key term is 'value' on all of them?

Comment: @lowercase - you can alias the column names in the result.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Brilliant! That did the trick nicely and we up and running. Thanks so much for sticking with my ambiguous questioning. haha.